# Regex - Invalid target for quantifier which converting C# Regex to JavaScript Regex

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am trying to convert C# email regular expression, which I have taken from [MSDN sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01escwtf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
@"^(?("")("".+?(?<!\\)""@)|(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#\$%&'\*\+/=\?\^`\{\}\|~\w])*)(?<=[0-9a-z])@)) (?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][\-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$"
```

which is like this:

```
^(?(")(".+?"@)|(([0-9a-zA-Z]((\.(?!\.))|[^!#\$%&\s'\*/=\?\^`\{\}\|~])*)(?<=[-+0-9a-zA-Z_])@))(?(\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}))$
```

but I am getting error for:

**?** : Invalid target for qualifier.

**?<=** : Lookbehind is not supported in JavaScript

I have need help in converting above Regex

Comment: You're over-validating. Use a simpler expression. After all the only way to know if an email address is truly valid is to actually send a message.

Comment: Was it used with IgnorePatternWhitespace flag?

Comment: My suggestion: search for a similar regex written in JavaScript. There are a large number of sites with regexes for email all over the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In .NET, this regex must have been used with `IgnorePatternWhitespace` and `IgnoreCase` flags since there is a space that prevents matching. Here is a [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f(%22)(%22.%2b%3f(%3f%3c!%5c%5c)%22%40)%7c((%5b0-9a-z%5d((%5c.(%3f!%5c.))%7c%5b-!%23%5c%24%25%26%27%5c*%5c%2b%2f%3d%5c%3f%5c%5e%60%5c%7b%5c%7d%5c%7c%7e%5cw%5d)*)(%3f%3c%3d%5b0-9a-z%5d)%40))+(%3f(%5c%5b)(%5c%5b(%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%5c.)%7b3%7d%5cd%7b1%2c3%7d%5c%5d)%7c((%5b0-9a-z%5d%5b-%5cw%5d*%5b0-9a-z%5d*%5c.)%2b%5ba-z0-9%5d%5b%5c-a-z0-9%5d%7b0%2c22%7d%5ba-z0-9%5d))%24&i=mail%40gmail.com&o=ix).

The problems you encounter when porting the regex to JS are caused by the fact that JS regex does not support lookbehinds and conditionals.

There is a conditional workaround for JS: .NET `(?(")"[^"]*"|\w+)` can be translated as `(?:(?=")"[^"]*"|(?!")\w+)`.

The lookbehinds are difficult to convert, but here, the first lookbehind does not seem appropriate. You are looking to find the closest set of unescaped double quotes. You can do it with `"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"`.

The second lookbehind is just checking if `@` is preceded by a letter or digit character. The easiest way to handle this is to add `[a-z0-9]` character class to the left of the `@` symbol and apply a `?` quantifier to the first group of this alternative, making a digit or a letter appear before `@` and the 1-character user part would still get matched.

So, you can use

```
/^(?:(?=")("[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*"@)|(?!")(([0-9a-z]((\.(?!\.))|[-!#$%&'*+\/=?^`{}|~\w])*)?[a-z0-9]@))(?:(?=\[)(\[(\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\])|(?!\[)(([0-9a-z][-\w]*[0-9a-z]*\.)+[a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]{0,22}[a-z0-9]))$/i
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/jJ4bY6/8) (note I also removed some unnecessary escape symbols).

Comment: At a general glance, this `(?: \b | [^_] ) ` is problematic. Not only will `[^_]` match anything but underscore, it forces more than 1 character before the @ symbol if not a word boundary.Also, the `(?=\[)` and `(?!\[)` are unnecessary since they could never be matched in the alternation cluster.

Comment: Agreed, that was sort of problematic. Since the original regex does not allow `_@gmail.com` I assume OP can safely use `\b` rather than `[^\W_]`. If the user part can have minimum 2 symbols, `[^\W_]` could be used, all depends on the requirements. As for the lookaheads, they are necessary to emulate a conditional construct.

Comment: The word boundary `\b` alone won't work because it matches `hello_@world.com` but is expecting `[a-z0-9]@`. And the lookahead's on `[` work, but aren't needed because it is a typical `^(?:\[+|[^\[]+)$` situation, where there is no `[` being matched on the right side of the alternation. In fact, both conditionals were superfalous to begin with.

Comment: Quite possible the conditionals are not that necessary, but I tried to show how it can be "emulated" in JS. Now, the regex will work as intended.

Comment: Conditionals are primarily used to test the state of a capture. There is really not any other use for them. In that respect, it can't be emulated in any engine that doesn't support testing captures.  Also, it's rare that both conditional paths are useful in regex. C# does, I think, only _expression_ conditionals which without any construct, mascarade as lookahead assertions, making them almost totally useless.